# In Perl 6, how can I replicate the behavior of Perl's List::Util::all?

Tags: raku, perl6-junction

I am trying to use a [`Junction`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Junction) to replicate behavior I am used to in Perl from [`List::Util::all`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util#all).

I am using the [`all`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/all) junction in the following statement:

```
# does not work
return not know(@possible-dates) and not know tell day all(@possible-dates);
```

not knowing what any of these functions do, I assumed that this statement would be equivalent to the following:

```
# works
my Bool $r = not know @possible-dates;
for @possible-dates -> $date {
  $r = $r && not know tell day $date;
}

return $r;
```

The for loop version returns the correct result, the junction version does not and I am trying to understand why.

Full code below to inform what all of the functions do:

```
my @dates = <May 15>, <May 16>, <May 19>, <June 17>, <June 18>, 
  <July 14>, <July 16>, <August 14>, <August 15>, <August 17>;

sub day (@date) { @date[1] }
sub month (@date) { @date[0] }

sub tell($data) {
  @dates.grep({ day($_) eq $data or month($_) eq $data });
}

sub know(@possible-dates) { @possible-dates.elems == 1 }

sub statement-one(@date) {
  my @possible-dates = tell month @date;

  # why is this not the same as below?
  return not know(@possible-dates) 
    and not know tell day all(@possible-dates);

  # my Bool $r = not know @possible-dates;
  # for @possible-dates -> $date {
  #   $r = $r && not know tell day $date;
  # }
  #
  # return $r;
}

sub statement-two(@date) {
  my @possible-dates = tell day @date;

  not know(@possible-dates) 
    and know @possible-dates.grep(&statement-one);
}

sub statement-three(@date) {
  my @possible-dates = tell month @date;

  know @possible-dates.grep(&statement-two);
}

sub cheryls-birthday() {
  @dates.grep({ 
    statement-one($_) 
      and statement-two($_) 
      and statement-three($_) 
  });
}

say cheryls-birthday();
```

Comment: Quick comment before I properly read your code. "Negated operators are special-cased when it comes to autothreading. `$a !op $b` is rewritten internally as `!($a op $b)`. The outer negation collapses any junctions, so the return value always a plain `Bool`." (From [Junction](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Junction).) May not be relevant...

Comment: Next thing that jumps out at me when focusing on `return not know(@possible-dates) and not know tell day all(@possible-dates)` is that you're using low-precedence `and` which [almost never does what you mean in a `return` statement](https://docs.perl6.org/language/traps#Loose_boolean_operators). Use `&&` instead, or use parentheses to say what you mean.

Comment: Kudos to @Aleks-Daniel Jakimenko-A for creating and promoting addition to the Traps page which made it easy to remember/link/explain the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the easiest answer is to do a

```
zef install List::Util
```

and then put a:

```
use List::Util 'any';
```

in your code.  There are some subtle differences between Perl 6's `any` and the `any` with Perl 5 semantics that is provided by http://modules.raku.org/dist/List::Util:cpan:ELIZABETH .

In Perl 6, `any` returns a `Junction` object.  In Perl 5 `any` is a function that you call on a list with a block to execute on.

Comment: I was delighted by this answer and wanted to say so. And then a quick google later while pondering something I was even more delighted -- I hadn't taken on board what I presume is the origin of your naming of your/our/Perl's ["Butterfly Plan"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Butterfly+Plan) ("two or more wings of a house are constructed at an angle to the core"). That's world class branding. `Inline::Perl5`, pure ports of P5 CPAN modules starting upstream, P6 installers that rely on P5 being already installed, P6 eco built around CPAN etc., and so on. Such beautiful pragmatism!  xx Inf

Comment: Interesting, using `all` from List::Util also doesn't return the result I expect.

Comment: The following doesn't work but... .oO ( `zef install List::Util:from<Perl5>` ... `use List::Util:from<Perl5> 'any'; ...` )

Comment: @Hunter McMillen: if you find any issues, could you make an issue for it at https://github.com/lizmat/List-Util ?  Or even better, make a Pull Request if you know how to fix it.

Comment: Liz, I'll happily delete my comment if you'd prefer to keep your clever naming under wraps.

Comment: @raiph: nah, everybody can use Google  :-)

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen any works great, I just got turned around by the short circuiting of `and`

Comment: .oO ( Python's Py3 Plan vs Perl's BP. A Python community cabal built an unsafe conventional nuclear reactor next door to their old wind power plant. They've now condemned the old plant and scheduled it for official demolition in 2020 even though it's still windy. Meanwhile, after years of arguing about the future of power, with one Perl sub-community maintaining their old solar power plant and another building a LFTR thorium reactor (safe but currently mostly misunderstood or ignored) , some friends of both communities have built cabling that allows power to be shared between the two plants. )